# Compare two arrays by key, create third array with unique value from second array and minimal from first array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this output:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0            
        [2] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [1] => 28
        [12] => 167516
        [13] => 237120
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 2
        [12] => 11
        [13] => 11
        [14] => 11
    )
```

I need this result:

```
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [14] => 11
    )
```

I know i can unique values in array with `$arr[3] = array_diff_key($arr[2], array_unique($arr[2]));`, but they has keys where values are not minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you have your arrays assigned as `$a1` and `$a2`. AFAIU, you need those elements from `$a1` having zero value.

```
$a1 = array_filter($a1, function($el) { return $el === 0; });
```

Now we would intersect arrays to retrieve matches. Unfortunately, *PHP* won’t let us to choose which values to retrieve, they will be taken from `$a1`:

```
$inter = array_intersect_key($a1, $a2);
```

Now we should choose maximals:

```
$result = array_map(function($e) use ($inter,$a2) { 
     $key = key($inter); next($inter); // we need key to lookup a2
     return $e > $a2[$key] ? $e : $a2[$key]; 
   }, $inter
);
```

Hope it helps.

**UPD** Or, whether you are sure that all zero-valued items came from `$a1`, you might simply:

```
$a3 = array_intersect_key(
  $a2,
  array_filter($a1, function($el) { return $el === 0; }) 
);
```

Comment: Thank you for help. It worked for me when i changed {return $el === 0;} to {return $el == "0";}

Comment: You are welcome. The necessity to change `===` to `==` means that your arrays contain amount as string, not as integer.

Comment: What if one of minimum elements equal for example - "2", not "zero". What can i do to leave minimum "2", not only zeros?

Comment: `return $el <= 2;` should do the trick. You are free to filter the array as you want.

Comment: Благодарю вас) Очень хотелось бы что бы скрипт мог просчитывать минимальные значения с первого массива, а при return $el <= 2; могут попадаться дубли из массива $a2 если будет приведен другой пример. Попробую разобраться.

Comment: Первое решение, до upd, не зависит от фильтра. Дублей не будет, если выбирать из первого массива, потом пересекать массивы и маппить на максимальное значение.

Comment: перепробовал разные решения, но все равно не получается вывести седьмой элемент в котором нет нуля(в моем примере - time=15 Program channel=11). Если у вас есть минутка, вот исходный код - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de1e1235f215f06402adcec1b0fd82eac0180d68

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70523/discussion-between-mudasobwa-and-user2337706).